# Suppose $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is closed and non-empty. Prove that $2A$ is closed., where $2A=\{2a: a\in A\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

My proof: Let $x \in 2A$, then there exists, $x=2a$ such that $a=\frac{x}{2} \in A$ . Since $A$ is a closed set, there exists a convergence sequence $(\frac {x_{n}}{2}) \to \frac{x}{2}.$ We have to show that $(x_{n})$ converges to $x$ as $n\to \infty$.

I got this far, I feel like I am going in a loop to solve this. What should I do after this?

Comment: I would use the notion of "continuous function" and not bother with sequences.

Comment: $f(x)=2x$ is a homeomorphism of $\Bbb R$ and $2A = f[A]$ is thus closed as homeomorphisms are closed maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be a convergent sequence of elements of $2A$, and let $x$ be its limit. For each $n\in\Bbb N$, let $a_n\in A$ be such that $2a_n=x_n$. Then $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):a_n=\frac{x_n}2$, and therefore$$\frac x2=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}2=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n.$$But $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\in A$, since $A$ is closed. In other words, $\frac x2\in A$. Therefore, $x\in2A$. Since the limit of every convergent sequence of elements of $2A$ belongs to $2A$, $2A$ is a closed set.